# How send value in collectd with perl script?

Tags: perl, collectd

I created this script and I would like use it in collectd.

I would like used [collectd-perl plugin](https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd-perl.5.shtml) but I don't know how to use it.

The goal is to count how many mail are sent by server.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $pathvalue = 'value.txt';
my ($value, $old_value) = (countModule(), old_value());


########## Main #############

main();

####### Functions #############
sub old_value {
    open(FIC,$pathvalue) or die return 0;
    my @fic = <FIC> ;
        foreach my $line (@fic)
        {
                chomp($line) ;
                return $line;   #return the old value
        }
}

sub countModule
{
    my $file = "mail.log";
    open my $fh, "<",$file or die return 0;
    my @contents = <$fh>;
    my @filtered = grep (/status=sent/ ,@contents);
    my $count = scalar @filtered;
    return $count;
}

sub new_value {
    my ($value) = @_;
    open (FICHIER, ">$pathvalue") || die ("Vous ne pouvez pas créer le fichier");
    print FICHIER "$value";
    close (FICHIER);
}   

sub main {
    new_value(countModule());

    if ($value >= $old_value) {
        print $value-$old_value;
    }else{
        print $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you studied the page you linked to, including the *Examples* part?

Comment: yes, I test this : 
my $vl= $value-$old_value;
print "$vl->{'plugin'} ($vl->{'type'}): $vl->{'values'}\n";

But I have this error  :
Can't use string ("0") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at ./collectd_mail.pl line 47.

What's $vl ?

Comment: $vl seems to be a hash reference. Store the value inside of it, probably as `$vl->{values} = [ $value - $old_value ];`.

Comment: Sorry but your solution doesn't work.

Can't use string ("0") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at ./collectd_mail.pl line 47. What's $vl ?

Comment: Don't assign 0 to $vl, it should be a hash reference.